# MySQL crash after enormous row locks

Tags: mysql, crash, locking, innodb

I'm using MySQL 5.7.14 x64 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Sometimes (randomly times at day) mysql crashing with this stack trace

```
11:44:40 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=65536
max_used_connections=369
max_threads=2800
thread_count=263
connection_count=263
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 3195125 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x2ee2b72b0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
13fe1bad2    mysqld.exe!my_sigabrt_handler()[my_thr_init.c:449]
1401c7979    mysqld.exe!raise()[winsig.c:587]
1401c6870    mysqld.exe!abort()[abort.c:82]
13ff1dd38    mysqld.exe!ut_dbg_assertion_failed()[ut0dbg.cc:67]
13ff1df51    mysqld.exe!ib::fatal::~fatal()[ut0ut.cc:916]
13ff0e008    mysqld.exe!buf_LRU_check_size_of_non_data_objects()[buf0lru.cc:1219]
13ff0f4ab    mysqld.exe!buf_LRU_get_free_block()[buf0lru.cc:1303]
1400305cb    mysqld.exe!buf_block_alloc()[buf0buf.cc:557]
13ff3767e    mysqld.exe!mem_heap_create_block_func()[mem0mem.cc:319]
13ff37499    mysqld.exe!mem_heap_add_block()[mem0mem.cc:408]
13ffd87f4    mysqld.exe!RecLock::lock_alloc()[lock0lock.cc:1441]
13ffd795c    mysqld.exe!RecLock::create()[lock0lock.cc:1534]
13ffd73a6    mysqld.exe!RecLock::add_to_waitq()[lock0lock.cc:1735]
13ffdcaaa    mysqld.exe!lock_rec_lock_slow()[lock0lock.cc:2007]
13ffdc6ce    mysqld.exe!lock_rec_lock()[lock0lock.cc:2081]
13ffd8cc7    mysqld.exe!lock_clust_rec_read_check_and_lock()[lock0lock.cc:6307]
140076fe3    mysqld.exe!row_ins_set_shared_rec_lock()[row0ins.cc:1502]
140072927    mysqld.exe!row_ins_check_foreign_constraint()[row0ins.cc:1739]
140072de8    mysqld.exe!row_ins_check_foreign_constraints()[row0ins.cc:1932]
140075d69    mysqld.exe!row_ins_sec_index_entry()[row0ins.cc:3356]
1400758a6    mysqld.exe!row_ins_index_entry_step()[row0ins.cc:3583]
140071b30    mysqld.exe!row_ins()[row0ins.cc:3721]
14007755a    mysqld.exe!row_ins_step()[row0ins.cc:3907]
13ffaad50    mysqld.exe!row_insert_for_mysql_using_ins_graph()[row0mysql.cc:1735]
13fe7a7d3    mysqld.exe!ha_innobase::write_row()[ha_innodb.cc:7489]
13f6e5531    mysqld.exe!handler::ha_write_row()[handler.cc:7891]
13f8e54de    mysqld.exe!write_record()[sql_insert.cc:1860]
13f8e916a    mysqld.exe!read_sep_field()[sql_load.cc:1222]
13f8e7af4    mysqld.exe!mysql_load()[sql_load.cc:563]
13f716e86    mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:3649]
13f7194b3    mysqld.exe!mysql_parse()[sql_parse.cc:5565]
13f71267d    mysqld.exe!dispatch_command()[sql_parse.cc:1430]
13f71368a    mysqld.exe!do_command()[sql_parse.cc:997]
13f6d82bc    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:300]
140105122    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2191]
13fe1b93b    mysqld.exe!win_thread_start()[my_thread.c:38]
1401c73ef    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstartex()[threadex.c:376]
1401c763a    mysqld.exe!_threadstartex()[threadex.c:354]
772859bd    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
773ba2e1    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

At this time active only 2 transactions

```
---TRANSACTION 1111758443, ACTIVE 565 sec
mysql tables in use 7, locked 7
7527 lock struct(s), heap size 876752, 721803 row lock(s), undo log entries 379321
MySQL thread id 166068, OS thread handle 1508, query id 112695582 localhost converter Waiting for table level lock
delete from pl

using

import_k2b_product_links ipl inner join k2b_products pSource on ipl.src_product = pSource.article and pSource.account_id = 22

inner join k2b_products pDest on ipl.dst_product = pDest.article and pDest.account_id = 22

inner join k2b_product_links pl on pl.src_product_id = pSource.id and pl.dst_product = pDest.id

where ipl.action = 1
---TRANSACTION 1111759716, ACTIVE 496 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 1
mysql tables in use 4, locked 4
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1304535248, 102060778 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 19436, OS thread handle 11664, query id 112301161 localhost exchange_central
LOAD DATA INFILE 'd:/kdm/temp/webCentral/ufrd1uwx.v2r'

    INTO TABLE k2b_orders

    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

(id_status, dt, account_id, sms_sended, params, update_ts, exported, id_editor, dt_offset, device_id, gen, changer_device_id, total, creator_device_id, id, dt_server, device_category_id, original_params, order_num, sended, editor_comment, admin_comment)
```

I don't understand why transaction 1111758443 Waiting for table level lock?

And why transaction 1111759716 lock 102060778 rows while it load just only one from external file and it showed in  undo log entries 1?

Which investigation I must done for known reason of this enormous locks and crash.

Thanks!

Comment: a) do you have any myisam tables? b) check which other tables got locked/used by the 2nd transaction that might interact with the first one c) check if you have triggers, foreign keys/cascaded deletes on your tables that may interact with one of the other tables d) I would try to do the import into a different table first (without transactions). Once it is loaded in, transfer it to the destination, maybe in small batches. Although I don't know the rest of your import script and how many rows you import, I would suspect this to be the source of your problem. e) Maybe update mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Two things make me think that the crash is not the 'real' problem.

Both queries in the log show 'huge' times, such as `ACTIVE 565 sec`.

And these are all quite large:

```
max_used_connections=369
max_threads=2800
thread_count=263
connection_count=263
```

When there are hundreds of threads simultaneously *active*, InnoDB stumbles over itself.  Throughput stalls, and latency goes through the roof.

One cure is to avoid so many connections.  This is sometimes best done at the client.  What is the client?  For example, Apache has `MaxClients`.  A dozen Apaches, each with `MaxClients = 50` would be trying to open 600 connections.  Probably one Apache cannot effectively handle 50 threads at once.  Lower that number.

Are there any `VIEWs` deceiving us?

Another thing to do is to pursue `table level lock`.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved.  Check for appropriate indexes.

```
import_k2b_product_links: INDEX(action, ...)
k2b_products: INDEX(account_id, src_product)   -- in either order
k2b_products: INDEX(account_id, dest_product)  -- in either order
k2b_product_links:  INDEX(src_product_id, dest_product_id) -- or PK, see below
```

Is `k2b_product_links` a many:many mapping table?  If so, get rid of `id auto_increment` as discussed [*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

The index suggestions, if useful, could speed up the `DELETE`, thereby cutting down on possible contention.